# Can I set extended properties to a meeting that i'm gonna create using Send button?

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, extended-properties

Can I set extended properties to a meeting that i'm gonna create using Send button from meeting window? 
Are there any alternatives for setting extended properties to o meeting besides creating the meeting using OfficeJs EWS request CreateItem?

Comment: Hi Tudor, you can't add random MAPI properties the meeting, but you can set custom props that can be read back later on the meeting (using the loadCustomPropsAsync API). However, they won't transit to the recipient, when you hit send. Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook Web Add-ins don't provide anything for creating meetings (except REST API calls). They are run in the context of current item only. You need to develop a COM add-in if you need to get access to a rich set of methods and properties available, i.e. the Outlook object model.